# Spinner value disappear after layout visibility is changed + specific flows

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I have a custom `list view` with layout contain two layouts, called upper and bottom.

upper layout contain spinner, set and remove buttons.
bottom layout contain `text view` and back button.

By default bottom layout is in `GONE` state and when the user clicks on `set` button `upper` layout is `GONE` and bottom is `VISIBLE` (clicking on back button in bottom layout will return upper bottom back).

my problem is spinner value is disappear after specific flows:

**Flow 1:**

1. Add two items
2. Click on SET button on the first item
3. Remove the second item
4. Click on 'Back' button on the first item

[image: Spinner value is disappear]

**Flow 2:**

1. Click on SET
2. Rotate screen
3. Click on Back

Just to be clear, spinner values are exist and if drop it down you'll found the names (and I have `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in my manifest).

So, why spinner value is disappear after those flows  ?

Here is my code:

**Names.java**

```
public class Names
{
    private String name;
    private int nameIndex;
    private Boolean isNameOnTop;


    public Names()
    {
        name = "";
        isNameOnTop = true;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNameIndex() {
        return nameIndex;
    }

    public void setNameIndex(int nameIndex) {
        this.nameIndex = nameIndex;
    }

    public Boolean getIsNameOnTop() {
        return isNameOnTop;
    }

    public void setIsNameOnTop(Boolean isNameOnTop) {
        this.isNameOnTop = isNameOnTop;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<Names> namesArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView lvNames;
    ListviewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ListviewAdapter(this, namesArray);
        lvNames.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_add)
        {
            namesArray.add(new Names());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**ListviewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public Activity context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Names> namesID;
    private boolean isDeleted;

    public ArrayList<Names> getNamesID() {
        return namesID;
    }

    public void setNamesID(ArrayList<Names> namesID) {
        this.namesID = namesID;
    }

    // Constructor
    public ListviewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Names> names)
    {
        super();
        setNamesID(names);

        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getNamesID().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Names getItem(int position) {
        return getNamesID().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
public class ViewHolder
    {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout_Upper;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout_Bottom;

        Spinner spNames;
        Button btn_set, btn_remove, btn_back;
        TextView tvChosen;

        int index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            holder.relativeLayout_Upper = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lvRow_upper_layout);
            holder.relativeLayout_Bottom = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lvRow_bottom_layout);
            holder.spNames = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spNames);
            holder.btn_set = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_set);
            holder.btn_remove = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
            holder.btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            holder.tvChosen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_chosen);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.index = i;

        if (isDeleted)
        {
            holder.spNames.setSelection(getItem(holder.index).getNameIndex());
            holder.tvChosen.setText("Chosen: " + getItem(holder.index).getName());

            if (getItem(holder.index).getIsNameOnTop())
            {
                holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        // pop spinner names
        String[] names = new String[]{"Tom", "Ben", "Gil", "Adam", "Moshe", "Adi", "Michael", "Yasmin", "Jessica", "Caroline", "Avi", "Yael"};
        final ArrayAdapter<String> spNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names);
        spNamesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spNames.setAdapter(spNamesAdapter);

        holder.spNames.setSelection(getItem(holder.index).getNameIndex());
        holder.spNames.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //holder.spNames.setTag(position);
                getItem(holder.index).setNameIndex(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        holder.btn_set.setTag(i);
        holder.btn_set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getItem(holder.index).setName(holder.spNames.getSelectedItem().toString());
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                holder.tvChosen.setText("Chosen: " + getItem(position).getName());
                holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getItem(holder.index).setIsNameOnTop(false);
            }
        });

        // remove
        holder.btn_remove.setTag(i);
        holder.btn_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                namesID.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                isDeleted = true;
            }
        });

        // back
        holder.btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getItem(holder.index).setIsNameOnTop(true);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:** contain `ListView` only.

**upper_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spNames" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SET"
        android:id="@+id/btn_set" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REMOVE"
        android:id="@+id/btn_remove" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**bottom_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Chosen:"
        android:id="@+id/tv_chosen"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BACK"
        android:id="@+id/btn_back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvRow_upper_layout">

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/upper_view"
            android:id="@+id/includeRow_register"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvRow_bottom_layout"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/bottom_view"
            android:id="@+id/includeRow_showData"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use INVISIBLE Instead of gone

Comment: @meda, thanks but `INVISIBLE` it's not good idea because it's keep the layout space (cause an empty space between the rows)

Comment: You mean to say the data is there in the spinner all the time if you click on it, it is shown, right??

Comment: @rj, yes the data is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ListviewAdapter, change:

```
    // back
    holder.btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getItem(holder.index).setIsNameOnTop(true);
        }
    });
```

to:

```
    // back
    holder.btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.relativeLayout_Upper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayout_Bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getItem(holder.index).setIsNameOnTop(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            // OR you can use this
            // holder.spNames.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have to wait 23 hours to award the bounty... Do you know to explain (please) why I need the notify method here?

Comment: Well, not gonna lie but your code is kinda messy so I didn't read every single line but I noticed this line:  `holder.spNames.setSelection(getItem(holder.index).getNameIndex());`. So I **guessed** when you remove the second item, the second item's view is reused by the first one, that's why your `Spinner` loses selections. So I used `notifyDataSetChanged();` to trigger `getView()` to set the correct selection again. Give me a minute I will check if my **guess** was true :D

Comment: Sadly, my guess was wrong, the first item still uses its old view. Actually, I think there's nothing wrong with your code but the render system (my guess again) because after removing the second item, press back, then tap on the Spinner, the expanded list is still scrolled to correct position of selected item, it just doesn't show selected item when it's collapsed (it's really weird!). So basically we fix that weird thing here by calling Spinner's `setSelection` again via `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: :) Thank you very much ! especially for your honesty

Comment: MAN, FINALLY I GOT IT.
It's really a bug of Android. You can just simply not use `notifyDataSetChanged()` (if you care about performance) but `holder.spNames.requestLayout();` <<<<<<< This works too!!!

Comment: Wow, good to know it's Android bug, do have a link? it's will be awesome

Comment: Now I'm confused, I thought it was a bug but I couldn't make a sample to prove it... Well, at least I tried... Let's call it a day....

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click on "Add" in the method onOptionsItemSelected() you add an object new names() into the list, and in the Names class, the value of attribute name is set to ""
I guess that's why you getting an empty item in the spinner.

Comment: No no no, you reset all spinners when the user add new item. please check yourself next time